# Mongoid: relations between embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have two collections in my DB-

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5281c15a617274166f150000"),
            "email" : "aerf@gmail.com",
            "nickname" : "Artem",
            "user_activities" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5281c19161727415d5000000"),
                    "activity_id" : ObjectId("5281c15a617274166f010000"),
                    ...
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5281c19161727415d6000000"),
                    "activity_id" : ObjectId("5281c15a617274166f020000"),
                    ...
                },
                       ...
            ]
        },
       ....
```

and

```
> db.monitor_symptoms.find().pretty()
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5281c15a617274166f000000"),
        "activities" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5281c15a617274166f010000"),
                "name" : "ASW"
                        ...
                },
                {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5281c15a617274166f010000"),
                "name" : "BSW"
                        ...
                },
                ...
       ],
       ...
    },
    ...
```

This is supported by the following models in my app-

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email, type: String, :default => ""
  field :nickname, type: String, :default => ""
  embeds_many :user_activities
end

class UserActivity
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :user
  has_to_many :activities, inverse_of: nil
end

class MonitorSymptom
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :activities
end

class Activity
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  embedded_in :monitor_symptom
end
```

I try next-

```
2.0.0p0 :090 >   user = User.first
 => #<User _id: 5281c15a617274166f150000, email: "aerf@gmail.com", nickname: "Artem"

2.0.0p0 :091 > user.user_activities.new(activity_id: "5281c15a617274166f010000")
 => #<UserActivity _id: 5281c15a617274166f150000, activity_id: "5281c15a617274166f010000"> 

2.0.0p0 :092 > user.save
```

And I catch an error:

> Mongoid::Errors::MixedRelations:  Problem:   Referencing a(n) Activity
>   document from the UserActivity document via a relational association
>   is not allowed since the Activity is embedded. Summary:   In order to
>   properly access a(n) Activity from UserActivity the reference would
>   need to go through the root document of Activity. In a simple case
>   this would require Mongoid to store an extra foreign key for the root,
>   in more complex cases where Activity is multiple levels deep a key
>   would need to be stored for each parent up the hierarchy. Resolution: 
>   Consider not embedding Activity, or do the key storage and access in a
>   custom manner in the application code.

Please help me to make this reference.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model which is embedded_in some other model can't have relationships other than embed...for your case `activity` is embedded in `monitor_symptom` it can't be refrenced from other document(hich you are doing in `user_activity`). When you have such a complex structure, it is better to use refrenced relationship between document rather than embed. For e.g. in between user and user_activity, monitor_symptom and activity then you can easily have refrenced relationship between activity and user_activity.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I need have one collection monitor_sympton and one collection for user. If I use refrenced relationship between documents - it creates a separate collections for docs